# Python connect to sql server from anaconda environment on mac give error

Tags: python, sql-server, anaconda, pyodbc, unixodbc

I want to connect python to sql server on mac M1 , I installed all the required files by microsoft using homebrew , when I'm not in  anaconda environment the isql command and pyodbc runs successfully when I activate conda environment I got this error :

> [01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib' : file not found

Please if anyone could help !

Comment: What version of conda are you running? M1 support was only added in [conda 2022.05](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/new-release-anaconda-distribution-now-supporting-m1), prior versions will be running under x86_64 emulation which probably won't work with the [M1 version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos) of ODBC 18 drivers installed in the /opt/homebrew folders.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply , I am running conda version 4.14.0